# how to pass an arguments to function to get a line plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment

I am trying to write a function to create time series plot (line graph). How do I pass an argument to function so that the plot is created? I tried different ways like using `aes_string` etc. but no success.

```
lineplotfun <- function(feature){
  ggplot(aes(x = 1:length(feature), y = feature), data = mtcars) +
  geom_line()
  }

lineplotfun(mpg)
```

I want to pass `mpg` as string or name.

Comment: Did you mean `lineplotfun(mtcars$mpg)`? Because that works fine, you code errors out.

Comment: What are you trying to pass in the argument? Variable name? Vector of data? Data frame?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with the code in the question.

1) `y` is not in `aes()`

2) if `ggplot2` is loaded, `mpg` is a `tibble`

3) `y = feature` with `data = mtcars` is meaningless

4) 1:length(feature) only makes sense if `feature` is a vector

One way of achieving what you want is by setting `data = NULL` and pass a vector to the function:

```
lineplotfun <- function(feature){
  require(ggplot2)
  ggplot2::ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = seq_along(feature), y = feature)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line()
}

lineplotfun(mtcars$mpg)
```

The result is:

[image: ggplot]